# Group separator in jsf validation messages

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2, resourcebundle

I have the following validator for the year of birth:

```
<f:validateLongRange minimum="1920" maximum="1992" />
```

The validation message is some kind of:

> "The year of birth must be between 1.920 and 1.992"

Now some of the users complain: "Do I have to put a dot between the 1 and the 9?"

The answer is of course "No", but can I somehow change the error message in a way that it doesn't show the separator?

(I have changed the default validation message in a custom message bundle using the placeholders {0} and {1} to insert the min and max value, but I think that is not important here, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number format is been set by [`LongRangeValidator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/LongRangeValidator.html) which in turn uses [`NumberConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html) to prepare the min/max values for the placeholders. So, you can unfortunately not use the *SubformatPattern* feature of the [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) API.

Your best bet is to use `validatorMessage` attribute instead

```html
<h:inputText validatorMessage="The year of birth must be between 1920 and 1992">
```

or to supply a custom validator which extends `LongRangeValidator` and does the message handling job differently (i.e. don't pass the converted min/max value as `String` to it, but just pass it unconverted). You should then be able to use the following message format:

```
The {2} must be between {0,number,#} and {1,number,#}
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. If I change the message format as you suggested, I get an exception: _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number_ I also tried some other example formats from the MessageFormat API with the same result.

Comment: But using the `validatorMessage` attribute solves the problem, even if the min/max values are el expressions. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I didn't expect the `IllegalArgumentException` to appear! After inspection it seems that the `LongRangeValidator` is converting the value to string by itself before passing to `MessageFormat`. This way you can indeed not use the `number` subformat. Sorry, I'll fix the answer.